# Position elements underneath each other

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble placing elements in my `HTML` directly underneath each other using `float` in the `CSS`.

What I have done is created a container class for my `div` and then placed a `button` and another `div` inside the container both with the `CSS` styling `float: right;`.

What I expected to happen is this.

[image]

And what actually happened was this.

[image]

---

**The Code**

*HTML*

```
<div class = "containDebug">
    <button id="btn_debug"><p>D</p></button>

    <div id="console_debug">
        <h1>Page Array</h1>
        <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
        <h1>GET</h1>
        <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
        <h1>POST</h1>
        <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

*SCSS*

```
#console_debug {
    float: right;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px #CCCCCC;

    pre {
       word-break: break-all;
       white-space:normal;
    }
}

#btn_debug{
    float: right;
}

.containDebug {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

*JavaScript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#console_debug").hide();
    $("#btn_debug").click(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#console_debug").toggle();
    });
});

$(document).click(function() {
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#console_debug').length) {
        if($('#console_debug').is(":visible")) {
            $('#console_debug').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

---

**JSFiddle**

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/xy967fc0/1/) so that you could see the code in action.

I appreciate any help in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to wrap your button in a `<div>`.

Since you are floating **both** the button and the console DIV they will appear next to one another instead of one on top of one another. By having two DIVs as the child of `.containDebug` they will both take up the full width of their container elements since they are block level elements.

```js
$("#btn_debug, #console_debug").click(function(e) {

  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#console_debug").toggle();

});
```

```css
#console_debug {
  display: none;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px #CCCCCC;
  pre {
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
#btn_debug {
  float: right;
}
.containDebug {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containDebug">

  <div>
    <button id="btn_debug">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="console_debug">
    <h1>Page Array</h1>
    <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
    <h1>GET</h1>
    <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
    <h1>POST</h1>
    <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
  </div>

</div>
```

Another option would be to clear the floated button.

```js
$("#btn_debug, #console_debug").click(function(e) {

  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#console_debug").toggle();

});
```

```css
#console_debug {
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px #CCCCCC;
  pre {
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
#btn_debug {
  float: right;
}
.containDebug {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containDebug">

  <button id="btn_debug">Button</button>

  <div id="console_debug">
    <h1>Page Array</h1>
    <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
    <h1>GET</h1>
    <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
    <h1>POST</h1>
    <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Note:** I simplified your JS by setting `#console_debug` to `display: none;` by default and letting jQuery's `toggle()` handle the display of it, whether you click on the button or the console. No reason to hide it with JS and test for it's visibility. Let jQuery and `toggle()` do the work for you.

Comment: Thank you. Just a note the `display: none` was great but the rest of the js code was there for the ability to click anywhere and the box still to disappear. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah okay, overlooked that part. I have updated the JS to do what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

See this Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/3s29ta79/

I have wrapped the button in a div with the class of `.clearfix`, and added the CSS to the top of the stylesheet.

This method ensures that a floated element doesn't affect the elements below or around it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Remove `float:right;` and add `text-align:right;` for `.containDebug` and `text-align:left;` for `#console_debug`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#console_debug").hide();
 $("#btn_debug").click(function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#console_debug").toggle();
 });
});

$(document).click(function() {
 if(!$(event.target).closest('#console_debug').length) {
        if($('#console_debug').is(":visible")) {
            $('#console_debug').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#console_debug {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px #CCCCCC;
  text-align:left;
    
    pre {
       word-break: break-all;
       white-space:normal;
    }
}



.containDebug {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "containDebug">
    <button id="btn_debug"><p>D</p></button>
    
    <div id="console_debug">
        <h1>Page Array</h1>
        <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
        <h1>GET</h1>
        <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
        <h1>POST</h1>
        <pre> Some text from PHP code </pre>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "clear: both;" to your #console_debug. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: both;` to `#console_debug`